# Actual page number and total pages numbers in Chrome print mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I need to create custom footer in print mode in Chrome. I have fixed positioned footer and I set bottom to 0. So footer displays on every page. I added `<p>` with class `footer-paragraph` and I tried to count elements with class name `footer-paragraph`. I got 1 element for 15 pages. Why I am getting only one element object when I have one element for each printed page? So I tried CSS. I found this:

```
@page {
   @bottom-center {
      content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages)
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work in newest Chrome. Chrome has his own footer which doesn't look good. Is there any trick which solves this?

Answer (score 0):

Too bad, That's what I read in this [page](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-css3-page-19990928)

"3.3.4. pages()

The 'pages()' function returns the total number of the pages in the document. This allows text such as "Page 1 of 5" to be inserted in margin boxes. This function is potentially expensive in terms of processing required, and only applies to paged media."